# Group an array of objects by a certain mutual property with `reduce` in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    todo: 'Shopping',
    isUrgent: false
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    todo: 'Dinner',
    isUrgent: true
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    todo: 'Doctor appointment',
    isUrgent: true
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    todo: 'Yard sale',
    isUrgent: false
  },
]
```

Now I want to transform it based on the value of `isUrgent` into this format:

```
{
  urgentTodo: [
    {
      id: '2',
      todo: 'Dinner',
      isUrgent: true
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      todo: 'Doctor appointment',
      isUrgent: true
    },
  ],
  notUrgentTodo: [
    {
      id: '1',
      todo: 'Shopping',
      isUrgent: false
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      todo: 'Yard sale',
      isUrgent: false
    },
  ]
}
```

I know that I can use `filter` and `map` to achieve this but was curious to know how to use `reduce` in this scenario in TypeScript.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce` with some conditions to do this:

```js
const x = [
  {
    id: '1',
    todo: 'Shopping',
    isUrgent: false
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    todo: 'Dinner',
    isUrgent: true
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    todo: 'Doctor appointment',
    isUrgent: true
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    todo: 'Yard sale',
    isUrgent: false
  },
]

const ans = x.reduce((agg,curr) => {
if(curr.isUrgent)
agg.urgentToDo.push(curr);

else
agg.notUrgentTodo.push(curr);
return agg;

},{ urgentToDo : [] , notUrgentTodo : []});

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Would appreciate the answer to be in TypeScript